# filter changelist records based on model's field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model that contains the following fields:

[image]

I added two button in changelist page and want to filter the list based on "active" field by clicking each of buttons , but i don't know how do that.

[image]

please help me, thankes

Comment: Django does this for you, just add list_filter = ('active',) in the django-admin and this should add a filter option for your active field.

Comment: @YaakovWeller If i want to filter by a two level foreign key(item have row and row have section, i want to filter items by section name) how to do that?

Comment: I think you would do something like this list_filter = ('row__section__name',).

Comment: Yes, it is . Thank you very much @YaakovWeller